# Returning CSV format from django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a working Django 1.8 site, and I want to add a RESTful API using django-rest-framework. I would like to support rendering to CSV and JSON formats, and am puzzling over how to do this.

In `api/urls.py` I have this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^organisation/$', views.organisation), 
]
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns,
                                 allowed=['json', 'csv'])
```

And I have this in `api/views.py`:

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

@api_view(['GET'])
def organisation(request, format=None):
    code = request.query_params.get('code', None)
    print 'format', format
    organisation = Organisation.objects.get(code=code)
    serializer = OrgSerializer(organisation)
    data = serializer.data
    return JSONResponse(data)
```

But if I go to `api/1.0/organisation.csv?code=123`, I still see:

```
format json
```

in the console.

What am I doing wrong? And how should I return CSV once I have managed to capture the format? (I suspect I'm probably doing the wrong thing by writing my own `JSONResponse`, already.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it. The trick is to install [djangorestframework-csv](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv), then add the following in settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
        'rest_framework_csv.renderers.CSVRenderer',
    ),
}
```

And then scrap the `JSONResponse` function in `views.py` and just do `return Response(serializer.data)` instead. Very easy in the end.

Comment: Note: in `views.py` you'll need `from rest_framework.response import Response`

Comment: Note: djangorestframework-csv seems unmaintained.

Answer (score 18):

If you just need to download CSV (without Model serialization etc)

```
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class CSVviewSet(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="export.csv"'
        writer = csv.DictWriter(response, fieldnames=['emp_name', 'dept', 'birth_month'])
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'emp_name': 'John Smith', 'dept': 'Accounting', 'birth_month': 'November'})
        writer.writerow({'emp_name': 'Erica Meyers', 'dept': 'IT', 'birth_month': 'March'})
        return response
```

Comment: Is there a way to have this handle requests that have the `Accept: text/csv` header, or would I need to write a CSVRenderer class for that?

Answer (score 12):

This is an old post, but I've seen the accepted answer sets the `CSVRenderer` as one of the defaults, which is not usually wanted.

I would implement the view this way:

```
...
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
from rest_framework_csv.renderers import CSVRenderer
from .... import OrgSerializer
...

class OrganizationViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Organisation.objects.all()
    http_method_names = ['get', '...list all the other verbs you want']
    serializer_class = OrgSerializer
    renderer_classes = tuple(api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES) + (CSVRenderer,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'code' in self.request.GET:
            code = self.request.GET['code']
            return Organisation.objects.filter(code=code)
        return Organisation.objects.all()
```

Of course, having the `django-rest-framework-csv` installed and `OrgSerializer` defined somewhere.

Then you can just set `'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer'` as your default renderer in settings and the rest framework will automatically return csv content if you request it on the `HTTP_ACCEPT` header - *just for this view*.

Comment: How can I define custom headers using this implementation?

Comment: @PedroHenrique If you mean to set the HTTP_ACCEPT header I mention, try running a django unit test and just defining: HTTP_ACCEPT='text/csv'. This works for ApiTestCase subclasses (DRF). If you want to call this view with the Accept header just follow the standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept

Answer (score 2):

I think that a `StreamingHttpResponse` should be the preferred way. With `django-storages` and `ViewSet` it looks more or less like this.

```
    @action(detail=True, methods=["get"])
    def download(self, request, pk=None):
        f = self.get_object()
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(
            streaming_content=f.file.chunks(), content_type="text/csv"
        )
        response[
            "Content-Disposition"
        ] = f'attachment; filename="{f.name}.csv"'
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
        return response
```

Also, `FileResponse` is basically a `StreamingHttpResponse` with some headers etc so both are great for this use case.