# Django REST-Framework serializer dataframe CSV file

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I list in Django restframework a external DB

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
```

...

```
        },
        'tec': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
...
        },
    }
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class TmaskMda02(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    uuid = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    filename = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    log = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    sha256 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    # Field renamed because it was a Python reserved word.
    import_field = models.TextField(db_column='import', blank=True, null=True)
    export = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    params = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mda00'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions
from .serializers import HomeSerializer
from .models import TmaskMda02


class HomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TmaskMda02.objects.using('tec').all()
    serializer_class = HomeSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import TmaskMda02


class HomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TmaskMda02
        fields = ('id', 'uuid', 'filename', 'log',
                  'timestamp', 'sha256', 'import_field', 'export', 'params')
```

All is fine

If I would like to display a CSV file or data from the API how to do it?

## np. CSV

[Link](https://dane.gov.pl/pl/dataset/2485,raport-szczepien-przeciwko-covid-19/resource/33256)

## np. Ext API

[Link](https://api.dane.gov.pl/1.4/resources/33256,dane-dla-wojewodztw/data)

Thank you for all your comments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning CSV format from django-rest-framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160609/returning-csv-format-from-django-rest-framework)

Comment: In the other side, I would like to download, for example, CSV I and Serraelizers in Rest_Framework. As in the described example, it gets to the base Postgres and serializers all fields in Rest_Framework